# How to get document id Firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to get document id for updating a data, but instead it create a new document id. How to get document id Firestore?

[image: My firestore]

Code :

```
    final String getID = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(currentUser.getUid()).collection("Documents").document().getId();

    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String inspectorName = editInspector.getText().toString().trim();
            final String marketLocation = editLocation.getText().toString().trim();

            progressUpdated.show();

            firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(currentUser.getUid()).collection("Documents").document(getID).update("inspectorName", inspectorName, "marketLocation", marketLocation).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                 @Override
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                          Toast.makeText(StartCounting.this, "Document updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          progressUpdated.dismiss();
                          dialogUpdate.dismiss();
                        }
                   }
             }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                      Toast.makeText(StartCounting.this, "Error : " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                      progressUpdated.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the document Id that you want the document to have?

Comment: i want to updating some data, but it requires specific document id. so i ask how to get that specific id?

Comment: Your problem is that you are creating a random id. You have to set your own Id or get the random Id just right after your create your document and store it in the document for future queries.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Racu , i will try :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not updating because :

The following code of line generates new id when you call the `getID` each time you call it and store in String.

```
String getID = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(currentUser.getUid()).collection("Documents").document().getId();
```

So i suggest you to store the id which you get from `getID` store under each user document. Something like when you create / generate document just add the String value of id under the userid field.

Comment: if you provide your document create code then maybe we can help you in proper way

Comment: I tried this answer but i getting error.  "db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).doc(...).getId()    is not a function"

Comment: it's not doc. It's `document` for android sir